# Prove that for A, B and C sets, A - ( B - C ) = ( A - B ) ∪ ( A ∩ C ) (Alternative to the proof given)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, alternative-proof

My proof:

Let A, B and C be arbitrary sets.

As a means to prove such a statement we are going to verify that

x ∈ A - ( B - C ) ⇔ x ∈ ( A - B ) ∪ ( A ∩ C )

Note that

x ∈ A - ( B - C ) ⇔ x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ ( B - C ) ⇔ x ∈ A ∧ ( x ∉ B ∨ x ∈ C ) ⇔ ( x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ B ) ∨ ( x ∈ A ∧ x ∈ C ) ⇔ x ∈ ( A - B ) ∨ x ∈ ( A ∩ C ) ⇔ x ∈ ( A - B ) ∪ ( A ∩ C )

Hence,

A - ( B - C ) = ( A - B ) ∪ ( A ∩ C )

Comment: don't forget to mark an aswer as "correct answer" to help users in comunnity

Comment: I did, mate.Hehehe

Comment: you make an "upvote", there is another empty check at left of answer

Comment: Oooh. My bad. I am newbie.

Comment: It will be helpfull if you do the same with your older questions :D

Comment: It says I am allowed to do it within 2 minutes.

Comment: Im talking about this https://imgur.com/CUNLMkm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A\setminus(B\setminus C) = A \cap (B\setminus C)^C $$
$$=A\cap(B\cap C^c)^c = A\cap(B^c \cup C)$$
$$= (A\cap B^c)\cup(A\cap C)$$
$$=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap C)$$